# Potential circular dependency with authentication using vuex and vue-router

Tags: authentication, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router, circular-dependency

I have an application with a vue-router routeguard checking if a user is authenticated (checks vuex user store for a user).  If user is null, the application redirects the user to authenticate.  In another store, I want to import the vue-router instance so that I can grab params from the current route for a vuex action.

1. Is this a potential circular dependency issue or does webpack resolve this?
2. Is this authentication using the vuex store and vue-router an anti-pattern?

Comment: I'm facing the same exact problem. Have you found a solution for this?